# Return multiples taxonomies with wp_get_object_terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a loop to display the posts of my Custom Post Type 'workshop'. Inside the loop I display the related terms of two taxonomies 'area' and 'group' using `wp_get_object_terms()`.

It works fine. However I'm struggling to control the order of the taxonomies when displayed. It should always be in first 'area' then 'group'.

The code to display the related taxonomies:

```
<?php $workshop_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array( 'area', 'group' ) );

if ( ! empty( $workshop_terms ) ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $workshop_terms ) ) {

            foreach( $workshop_terms as $term ) {
                echo esc_html( $term->name );
            }
    }
} ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) accepts a third parameter which is an [array of arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) passed to [`WP_Term_Query::get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/get_terms/) which runs the actual SQL queries for the specific term request, and one of the arguments is named `orderby` which accepts term fields like `name` and `taxonomy`.

So you can use that 3rd parameter and set the `orderby` to `taxonomy` (and `order` to `ASC`) like so:

```php
$workshop_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array( 'area', 'group' ), array(
    'orderby' => 'taxonomy',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
) );
```

Or the other way, is of course, call `wp_get_object_terms()` once for each of the taxonomies... ✌

Comment: Thanks a lot @SallyCJ, that did the trick!

Comment: Glad it helped! But seriously, the other possible way is using [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the terms at PHP level, i.e. after you retrieved the terms in the default sorting using `wp_get_object_terms()`. I deliberately did not include that in my answer, though.. :)